# Resize navigation bar on workbench MySQL

Tags: database, navigation, resize, schema

i would like to know if it’s possible to resize navigation bar on MySQL workbench, the side where you can see the scheam’s section .
thank you in advance.

Comment: someone knows if its possible?

Answer (score 0):

put the cursor on the line over object info and pull it down. it's a simple adjustment of view.